# How to send a Jupyter\Ipython cell execution into celery worker?

Tags: python, ipython, celery, jupyter

So I want to execute my Jupyter\Ipython cell on a distributed Celery tasks cluster. I wonder if it is possible and how to somehow capture  a cell (and required surrounding variables) as an executable function to send it to Celery?

Comment: You could certainly try and implement this.   The main issue you may have in celery, is that things must be pickleable to be used in Celery, so it depends what is in the variables / state you want to send over.